# Why is this hard-science question marked as a duplicate of a non hard-science question?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, exact-duplicates

[This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/138065) has been marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/96337) despite the former having the [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) tag.

[This former meta discussion](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6621) explains why it should not be marked as a duplicate.

Has there been a change in policy that would result in doing so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see that one of the voter for closure is Community. This means that the OP got the prompt that a possible answer could be provided by the other question and indicated that the indicated question solved their problem.

If the OP indicates that their problem is solved by another question, even though the tags are different, there is little we can do, aside from requesting them to update the tags.

Comment: In addition there might be a valid answer "hard enough" in the other question even though it didn't specifically ask for it.